# insert foreign key value laravel with migration in laravel

Tags: laravel, insert, foreign-keys, default-value, migrate

**I want to insert foreign key when I will migration than add a foreign key value in 1**

```
`public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->after('email')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
        $data = [
            'name' => 'admin',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'role_id' => 1,
            'password' => bcrypt('123456'),
        ];
        App\User::create($data);
    }`
```

Here is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ywCW.png) of the  users table

Comment: `role_id` exists in referenced table?

Comment: yes, First i insert data in role table than insert user table

Comment: is  `role_id`  fillable   exist in your model? Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good practice to seed data inside Migrations.

Make sure `role_id` exists in a referenced table.

Also make sure `role_id` is not gaurded and exist in your fillable array of your `User` Model.

```
$fillable = ['role_id']
```

I would suggest creating a seeder then run the seeder after migration.

```
php artisan make:seed User
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

create migration set defualt value 1 in foregin key

```
 $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->after('email')->nullable()->default(1);
```